# Calculate ring of integers for roots of cubic polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Consider the polynomials

$$f_ 1(X ): =X^ 3-X^2+1$$

and

$$f_2(X):=X^ 3+X+ 1$$

and their roots $c_1\in\mathbb{C}$ of $f_1$ and $c_2\in\mathbb{C}$ of $f_2$. Is there a concrete way to calculate the ring of integeres of $\mathbb{Q}(c_1)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(c_2)$? Can someone recommend a script for this problem?

Comment: These curves are particularly easy — I’ve recently done it myself. You know in each case that $\Bbb Z[c_i]$ is a subring of the ring of integers of its field. You easily calculate the discriminant of the subring as the Norm of $f'_i(c_i)$ (up to sign). In both cases, this number is a prime. I think that should set you in the right path.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free script by J.S. Milne called [Fields and Galois Theory](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FT.pdf), and one called [Algebraic Number Theory](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ANT.pdf)